# Linking RFID tags with MFRC522 module in Python Flask to access student database using Raspberry pi3

Tags: python, html, css, rfid

I just started learning Python about 2 months ago for a university project I'm working on.

I wanted to create a "university" webpage that could read RFID card tags to access different HTML files (student files) depending on the unique id number of the card tag. The code itself shows no errors but the problem is: the HTML that I wish to access does not appear when I place the tag in the scanner. The scanner itself is working in a basic read and write file unrelated to the project so I'm sure the scanner is working. So, the question is: is there a better way to fix this and a link recommendation to study to get the idea working?

EDIT: I'll rephrase the question, does anyone know of a method to connect the Flask server with a read and write file in a RFID tag with the specific third party module used?

Function: once an RFID tag is shown in the scanner, the display has to change that is programmed on the specific RFID tag.

Here is the relevant information in the Python Flask File:

```html
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from flask import Flask, render_template
import SimpleMFRC522


#HTML & CSS to Python Flask Connection (Web Server)

frame_python = Flask(__name__)

@frame_python.route('/')
def frame_main():
    return render_template('Main.html') .... # cut it short cuz not needed


#RFID Student section

@frame_python.route('/Student/Student_Welcome')
def frame_stud_welcome():
    
     
    reader = SimpleMFRC522.SimpleMFRC522() #information from a different file below
    id = reader.read()
    a = 81143208559            #Variables a,b and c are the uid# of the card tags
    b = 628549754026
    c = 985039970922
    
    try:
     if a == id:
      return render_template('stud1_welcome.html')
     elif b == id:
      return render_template('stud2_welcome.html')
     elif c == id:
      return render_template('stud3_welcome.html')
    
    finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    frame_python.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8080,debug=True)
    
    
    
    
    
#Faculty Section
```

The stud1_welcome.html file:

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
            <meta name="description" content="Middle C, Christ at the center!">
            <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, MySQL, Python & Flask Python add-on">
            <meta name="author" content="name">
            
            <title>Smart Campus Information Board | Welcome!</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css">
        </head>
        
    
    <section id="background">
    
        <body>
          
            <header>
                <div class="container">
                 <div id="Branding">
                  <h1><span class="highlight">Smart Campus</span> Information Board</h1>
                </div>
            </header>
        
        <section id="logo">
            <div class="container">
                <img src="/static/img/AMA_logo.png">
                <h3>AMA International University Bahrain</h3>
                <p>Student ID accepted! Welcome Student 1!</p>
            </div>    
        </section>
        
        
        <section id="choices">
            <div class="container">
                <form>
                  <button type="Back to Menu" class="button_1"><a href="{{ url_for('frame_main') }}">Guest</a></button>
                </form>
            </div>    
        </section>
        
    </section>
        
         <footer>
        <p>SCIB Designs, 2019</p>
         </footer>
        </body>
     </html>
```

SimpleMFRC522() is a file with a library that I took from a tutorial (https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-rfid-rc522/).

```html
# Code by Simon Monk https://github.com/simonmonk/

import MFRC522
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
  
class SimpleMFRC522:

  READER = None;
  
  KEY = [0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF]
  BLOCK_ADDRS = [8, 9, 10]
  
  def __init__(self):
    self.READER = MFRC522.MFRC522()
  
  def read(self):
      id, text = self.read_no_block()        
      while not id:
          id, text = self.read_no_block()  
      return id, text

  def read_id(self):
    id = self.read_id_no_block()
    while not id:
      id = self.read_id_no_block()
    return id

  def read_id_no_block(self):
      (status, TagType) = self.READER.MFRC522_Request(self.READER.PICC_REQIDL)
      if status != self.READER.MI_OK:
          return None
      (status, uid) = self.READER.MFRC522_Anticoll()
      if status != self.READER.MI_OK:
          return None
      return self.uid_to_num(uid)
  
  def read_no_block(self):
    (status, TagType) = self.READER.MFRC522_Request(self.READER.PICC_REQIDL)
    if status != self.READER.MI_OK:
        return None, None
    (status, uid) = self.READER.MFRC522_Anticoll()
    if status != self.READER.MI_OK:
        return None, None
    id = self.uid_to_num(uid)
    self.READER.MFRC522_SelectTag(uid)
    status = self.READER.MFRC522_Auth(self.READER.PICC_AUTHENT1A, 11, self.KEY, uid)
    data = []
    text_read = ''
    if status == self.READER.MI_OK:
        for block_num in self.BLOCK_ADDRS:
            block = self.READER.MFRC522_Read(block_num) 
            if block:
              data += block
        if data:
             text_read = ''.join(chr(i) for i in data)
    self.READER.MFRC522_StopCrypto1()
    return id, text_read
    

    
  def write(self, text):
      id, text_in = self.write_no_block(text)        
      while not id:
          id, text_in = self.write_no_block(text)  
      return id, text_in


  def write_no_block(self, text):
      (status, TagType) = self.READER.MFRC522_Request(self.READER.PICC_REQIDL)
      if status != self.READER.MI_OK:
          return None, None
      (status, uid) = self.READER.MFRC522_Anticoll()
      if status != self.READER.MI_OK:
          return None, None
      id = self.uid_to_num(uid)
      self.READER.MFRC522_SelectTag(uid)
      status = self.READER.MFRC522_Auth(self.READER.PICC_AUTHENT1A, 11, self.KEY, uid)
      self.READER.MFRC522_Read(11)
      if status == self.READER.MI_OK:
          data = bytearray()
          data.extend(bytearray(text.ljust(len(self.BLOCK_ADDRS) * 16).encode('ascii')))
          i = 0
          for block_num in self.BLOCK_ADDRS:
            self.READER.MFRC522_Write(block_num, data[(i*16):(i+1)*16])
            i += 1
      self.READER.MFRC522_StopCrypto1()
      return id, text[0:(len(self.BLOCK_ADDRS) * 16)]
      
  def uid_to_num(self, uid):
      n = 0
      for i in range(0, 5):
          n = n * 256 + uid[i]
      return n
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about what it is you're doing, but just looking at the source code of the third-party module I can tell you that SimpleMFRC522.read() returns a tuple. When you do this:

```
id = reader.read()
```

id is now a tuple, not a single value - that's why your if-statements aren't executing.

My guess is that you can fix this by doing one of the following:

- use `id = reader.read_id()`
- use `id, _ = reader.read()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! unfortunately, I have tried both the lines you suggested but it did not seem to work. I got an idea on having a blank input form (or a dynamic content I think) on flask acting like a password  and once the RFID scanner obtains the ID number from the card, it would then return the new page, but am not sure how to do it or if it would work. Thoughts?